# How to identify the roles that taking up more cost in snowflakes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Help me with the query that gives details of roles and cost contributed by each role to the over all billing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to accurately determine which roles are spending the most on your compute is to separate the warehouses by role, so that each role has their own warehouse cost.  Otherwise, it is very difficult to estimate the cost associated with a role based on their query history.  You could estimate it by dividing the per-second credit costs to each query by how many queries were executing at that time, but that's a complex query.  Your other choice is a rough-estimate by taking the total duration of queries for each role using query history.  That'll give you an idea of which roles are using the most compute, but not accurately by any means.