# Users/roles Mapped to the warehouse

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Please help me with the query to find the warehouses that are allowed to use for a specific user/role in snowflakes(or) for all the users and roles in snowflakes instance.

Answer (score 0):

As an example metadata query to see which roles are granted access to a warehouse:

```
use role securityadmin;
show grants on warehouse warehouse_name;
```

Replace warehouse_name with the name of your warehouse and use whatever role you prefer as long as it has visibility into the warehouse.

Then you can execute this command if you'd like to see which users have a certain role:

```
show grants of role role_name;
```

Doc References:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-grants.html
- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-overview.html

Comment: I was actually looking for the query that could referer to the system metadata tables and gets the details of all users and corresponding warehouse names in one shot.

Comment: Users don't exactly correspond with a warehouse.  Users are granted roles and each role can be granted access to warehouse.  Of course, you are welcome to create custom scripts to pull data from the Account_Usage views and/or loop through users and their roles/grants.    

If you're looking for a compute cost breakdown by role, similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61856146/how-to-identify-the-roles-that-taking-up-more-cost-in-snowflakes

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that the relationship is between roles and warehouse. Do we have a query based on the metadata table where  one can get information about the roles and corresponding warehouses that each role is allowed to use?

Comment: I would make a clarification here - credits are billed based on warehouse usage (i.e., it depends on the size of the warehouse and duration for which the warehouse is in a running state).  Multiple users with different/same roles running queries in parallel on the same warehouse would result in the same amount of credit consumption as a single user with the same role running one query on the warehouse for the same duration. Hence, this may not give you the results you are looking for, and warehouse level billing reports are more accurate.

Comment: If you want some other options regarding built-in views in Snowflake, there is the account_usage.query_history view (https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html).  This has some useful columns.  Additionally, you can look for options joining the WAREHOUSE_METERING_HISTORY view to this view.  I don't personally have any JOIN SQL to offer, but you can look into that as well.